# Pagination on huge data

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have a simple table `test_table` with fields:

> id, machine, ip_address, incdate

**'id'** is an auto_increment int field and a primary key.
I am displaying simple list records without any WHERE condition on a page with pagination.
My table has records near about **5,000,000**.

Now the problem is that when I click on the first pages(e.g. 1, 2, 3, ..., 20, etc), data comes very fast like in milliseconds but when I click directly on the last page number (or a few last pages) it takes time up to 1 or more minutes.

I am using a following simple query to get data,

```
SELECT id, machine, ip_address, incdate 
FROM test_table
ORDER BY id
LIMIT <start-index>, <number-of-records>;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Same concern here...

Comment: How much is a "lakhs"?

Comment: @Erik 1 lakh = 100,000

Comment: There are quite a lot of tutorials on paging large datasets out there. Do none of those help?

Comment: You have problem in counting number of rows in table for paging calculation.

Comment: @NavjotSingh No, don't think so..

Comment: @Strawberry Yes there are but this problem is quite common and the mysql doesn't seem to have solution, is it?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using, and which storage engine?

Comment: Server version: 5.5.34 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, LIMIT in general is not optimal way to retrieve data from the large table. It will load start-index + number-of-records rows from the table, doing the table scan.

What you want to do is to avoid loading that (potentially) large volume of rows.

There are many ways how you can approach it, depending on different factors. If your ID is monotonously increased and you know it is does not have holes, you can calculate the ID and use WHERE id >=x AND id <=y

In most of the cases, this is not something you can rely on, though. MariaDB has [quite nice article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) showing some of the other available optimization techniques.